# Can't rename, No such file or directory

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have a root folder (03_COMPLETE), inside which are 40 subfolders two levels down (all called CHILD_PNG) that contain .png files I want to rename. There are 6 complete folders I have to go through, with tens of thousands of files. All files are currently named like this: *123456_lifestyle.png*, I want them named to *lifestyle_123456.png*.

My code:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -iname '*.png' -print0 | xargs -0 /usr/local/bin/rename -v 's/\/([0-9]+)_([A-Za-z]+[0-9])/\/$2_$1/'\;
```

If I run this on an individual folder of .png files (without using -mindepth) it renames them. However if I run it on the root 03_COMPLETE directory to try and do all the renaming at once, I get lines of errors like this:

> Can't rename
>   '/Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/RETOUCHING/04_DELIVERY_PNG/Computer1/03_COMPLETE/06052017_NYS5_W_1263_Output/CHILD_PNG/123456_lifestyle.png'
>   to
>   '/Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/RETOUCHING/04_DELIVERY_PNG/Computer1/03_COMPLETE/NYS5_06052017_W_1263_Output/CHILD_PNG/123456_lifestyle.png':
>   No such file or directory

I think it might have something to do with the names of the folder 1 level down (eg. here NYS5_06052017_W_1263_Output) because it did rename on a couple of folders named Bustform_000. Most of the folders though start with a number like 06052017.

I can't figure out why this will work at the .png folder level but won't work on the root folder, and why it will rename in a few folders but most of them it won't.

Also what is weird is that in the error it says it is trying to rename *123456_lifestyle.png* to the same filename. Why would it do that? Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest to insert one space before `\;`.

Comment: @Socowi: Perl's standalone rename command creates directories if necessary.

Comment: @Cyrus Yep, just noticed that and have tried it. Didn't work :(

Comment: This script worked on folders inside 03_COMPLETE called /Bustform_000/CHILD_PNG, /OnFigure_000/CHILD_PNG but did not work on anything like /07062017_NYS5_W_1293_OUTPUT/CHILD_PNG so I'm suspicious that it something about those folder names that is preventing the script.

Comment: As I've just noticed, `\;` is not part of the `xargs` command, but belongs to the `-exec` option from `find` command. Thus it is unnecessary in your command.

Comment: Took out ``\;`` no change to script behavior

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
find 03_COMPLETE -type f | xargs -n 1 rename -n 's|/([^_/]*)_([^_/]*).png$|/$2_$1.png|'
```

Remove `-n` if output is okay.

Comment: This does work, however if there are any PNG's already renamed to the desired standard (eg. lifestyle_123456.png) this script will name them back again to 123456_lifestyle.png. Is there a way to stop that happening? What was good about my original regex being so specific is that it would ignore any files that didn't match to avoid renaming anything that was already correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could change directory into each of the `CHILD_PNG` directories and run a single `rename` in there on all the files so you don't exec a new `rename` for every single file:

```
find 03_COMPLETE -type d -name CHILD_PNG -execdir bash -c "cd {}; rename -n '...' *.png" \;
```

Comment: I tried this, nothing happened. No errors, nothing.

Comment: I didn't put the actual `rename` code in - I left that for you - I was demonstrating a technique because you said you have code that works in a single directory and I assumed you would put that in where I left the ellipsis (`...`).

Comment: Yep, I added the rename code in place of `'...'` but literally nothing happened.

Comment: Mmmm.. I must have misunderstood something about your setup. Try removing the `rename` part and in its place put `pwd; ls *png`

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your original Regex is, it matches the directory names of the form "xxxxx_yyyyy" and tries to convert them into "yyyyy_xxxxx", which, of course, doesn't exist. Since you're interested in changing only the filenames, and all of them end with .png, you can use the below Regex. Additionally, as you're trying to match a literal '/', you can choose a different character like '|' as delimiter to make the Regex easier to read

```
's|/([0-9]+)_([A-Za-z]+[0-9]*)(\.[Pp][Nn][Gg])|/$2_$1$3|'
```